# Extracting results from a mySQL union query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck on an mysql query. I usually just put the result set into an array and use `var = $row['column'];` . I am unable to do that this time. The query is as such.

```
$dbTaskRecords = mysql_query("Select Time, TruckId, TaskNo, PickupLocation, DropOffLocation
From booking 
Where driver='$driver' 
    And Date= CAST('$Date_search' AS DATE) 
Union All
Select Time, TruckId, TaskNo, PickupLocation, DropOffLocation
From returnbooking
WHERE driver='$driver' 
    And Date= CAST('$Date_search' AS DATE) 
Order By TaskNo Asc");
```

If I try to use:
`$row = mysql_fetch_array($dbTaskRecords);`

I get an error.

How do I go about getting the outputs to variables?

Thanks guys.

Comment: You could do a `var_dump($row)` and find out the contents of the row. Just an idea...

Comment: Cheers Ioannis. I tried it and the result is NULL

Comment: issue the query you get via mysql_client first and see if you get an error, please give feedback

Comment: What's the error you 're getting? Perhaps it's indeed something else, since I just tried a UNION and it worked perfectly.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: What syntax did you use to output the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

this means that your query has an error

try to add this line before fetching the content

```
if (!$dbTaskRecords) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that if statement does not return anything.

Comment: Yeah it was the Query. There was a column that has had a name change since that code was written. Sorry to bother you on something so silly.

Answer (score 1):

UNION shouldn't change anything, it just allows you to get results from another source following the same SELECT scheme.. are you sure your error doesn't exist elsewhere?

Comment: I did have a silly spelling error but after fixing it I am still having the same issue with trying to create an array from the result.

Comment: did you run the query in a console? did it select as it should?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the results in a tabular format here is the code.

```
<table>
<?php
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
 {
 ?>             
  <tr>
  <td><?=$info['Time'];?></td>
  <td><?=$info['TruckId'];?></td>
  <td><?=$info['TaskNo'];?></td>
  <td><?=$info['PickupLocation'];?></td>
  <td><?=$info['Dropf'];?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php  
 }
 ?>
 </table>
```

if you want to assign variable just give like this say variable = $info['TruckId']

Comment: Cheers Vikram. I do use that method. The issue I have is that I can't create the $info = mysql_fetch_array($data); from the UNION query.